Alternatives to gripper_controller on OSX
I am currently following the MoveIt tutorials using the Robostack setup on ROS 2 Humble, running on macOS. Unfortunately, the gripper controller lacks official support for macOS, as indicated here. Are there any alternative solutions or approaches you would recommend?

Can you try to remove this part and compile it from source? Maybe we can fix this, as it comes from a pre-c++17 time.
Furthermore, we have a new gripper controller proposal. But you will have to manually merge this into humble, or use the rolling development version with the branch from the PR.

I attempted that too. There is just a chain of errors that pop up, starting with:
/Users/vivek/ros2_ws/src/packages_from_source/gripper_controllers/include/gripper_controllers/hardware_interface_adapter.hpp:169:82: error: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'rep' (aka 'long long') to 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') [-Werror,-Wsign-conversion]
    double command = pid_->computeCommand(error_position, error_velocity, period.count());
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
1 error generated.

Ignored warnings here.
